# Can a input type:submit display a graphic by any means?

Tags: html, forms, button, webforms, submit

Can I use CSS or Javascript to change the way an HTML submit button displays **without** changing the input type (or any of it's HTML)

I need to change the way a button looks from a form that is being served by a web service, but for some reason using the remove and replace method I have used on the other buttons totally breaks the form (it stops submitting properly).

My last chance to get the look of this form right is to be able to replace the button without affecting the HTML of the form. Any ideas?

Comment: You can change the style of the button via JavaScript.

Comment: can I do that without changing its type? if so, how?

Comment: Just change it with CSS?

Comment: I don't think submit can be styled with CSS, can they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling the input - only for submit -> `input[type=submit]`

I`ve made a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XBsyK/1/). Works perfectly in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use button as submit control, you can use image also, then all your problems will be solved:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/submit.gif" HEIGHT="30" WIDTH="173" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form">
```

Comment: As indicated in the question, this is not a viable solution

Comment: bur can you explain why you can't change input type maybe there is solution

Comment: because, when I do the form submits incorrectly. the form is running from a SOAP server, and incorrect URL's are passed. I can't find where these URL's are set, so can't fix.

Comment: I see what you are saying, hide submit button, add image submit and attach javascript to it. If submit button has id for example "submit" add javascript to image submit "submit.submit();" and it will submit like your button is clicked.